# do the limit exists for $(z+1/z)^2$ at origin.?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=(z+1/z)^2$ is the given function . How to find whether the function is differentiable at origin or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$f(z) = z^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{z^2}$$
This clearly shows that $f(z)$ has a pole of order $2$ at the origin, and is therefore meromorphic there, and not holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

To see it in a more direct sense, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

Consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(ix)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (xi)^{2} +2 +1/(xi)^{2}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -x^{2} +2 -1/x^{2}=- \infty$.

Now consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^{2} +2 +1/x^{2}= \infty$.

In the first limit, we are looking at the value of of the limit strictly on the imaginary axis and in the second, we are looking strictly along the real axis. But one approaches $-\infty$ infinity and the other approaches $\infty$. Ignoring the fact that we of course have the limits going to $\pm \infty$, we see that they are moving in different directions entirely. So, it seems clear now that the limit does not exist.